Psychological horror from mid-2000s with Max von Sydow or Maximillian Schell
Here's what I remember:

Came out in early 2000s - saw it on an HBO preview weekend I think.
Dozing while it was on so just saw bits and pieces.

Either Max von Sydow or Maximillian Schell (MS) - I can't tell them
apart sometimes.

Plot was a weird doctor-type (MS?) and his son in some type of
materialist hellhole mansion (because apparently only the rich can
be twisted).

Son brings a woman home and there's weirdness throughout the movie
about her seeing and hearing things she's not supposed to see.

At the end of the movie, it turns out she's not the first and MS is
doing "things" to the women, something about their brains, I think
it was a Stepford Wives kind of thing.

Final scene of the movie, or close to it - the son is in on it,
she's strapped into a chair and they're about to do X to her, and
she screams "I don't deserve this!" and MS says something very
Nietzsche-an to her, can't remember what.


Any ideas?

Was this movie in English as looking through a lot of these two actor's history it shows they have done a lot of none English films.

Have you looked at the mid-2000s output of these two actors in IMDB?  If so and no result, how sure are you of the actors or the date?

I tried RTFIMDB and didn't find anything, which brought me here. I am not 100% sure about the actors but more than 50% sure - maybe it was just a Teutonic-looking guy who'd worn a WWII German officer's uniform in other films.

The mid-2000s comment was when I saw it, and the period in the movie seemed contemporary based on dress and technology (cars, computers, etc)

@chcuk - now that you mention it, I am trying to remember and I am not sure! Funny how memory works - I thought of that last line as being spoken until you asked.

You don't need to edit your original post. Clicking the accept button tells us you've found your answer.

I did want to mention I was wrong in the OP about the star - it's neither sydow nor schell.

A bit late with this. ;) You're looking for the Canadian thriller Blood Relations from 1988. From IMDb:

Marie (winningly played by ravishing redhead stunner Lydie Denier) and her troubled fiancé Thomas (likable Kevin Hicks) go to Thomas' massive family estate to see his stern brain surgeon father Dr. Andreas Wells (the excellent Jan Rubes) and his ailing wealthy grandfather Charles MacLeod (a fine turn by the great Ray Walston). Marie soon discovers that there's something very sinister going on inside the swanky abode. 

Marie definitely sees things she's not supposed to in that mansion: her fiance's old father (played by Czech actor Jan Rubes) is experimenting on women there in order to get his braindead wife a new brain. The film ends with Marie strapped to a chair, screaming "I don't deserve this!" Here's the trailer:




Late?  What's 2 years amongst friends?  ;o)  +1 just for digging it out, although it's probably the right answer as well.

That'll do, Walt. That'll do.

This is definitely the right movie - here's a copy from archive.org. https://archive.org/details/blood-relations-1988

Not sure if this is it. No MS but plot could be the same.
Movie is called HYSTERIA made in 97.

I don't think this is right but upvoting the effort. Thanks.
